# Nash equilibrium for big data

Tags: computer-vision

How effective is Nash-equilibrium for big data cases in scenarios like crowd and traffic monitoring? 
Crowd and traffic scenarios are competitive environments which suit well to Nash-Equilibrium. Are there algorithms using Nash-Equilibrium which are successfully deployed?